# Control-Z control-W interchanged pycharm

Tags: pycharm

It is silly but on my pycharm installation on Linux Mint (ubuntu 16.04) the control-z and control-w are interchanged. I'd erased all settings on pychamg config but nothing works. I even installed a new comunity version but the keys remain stubornly interchanged.

All other applications I use just work right (So no keyboard problem)
Does anybody have a hint on why this is so?

Comment: Is there anything unusual about your keyboard? Is it a standard QWERTY keyboard? Is it set to standard US English?

Comment: Is a british layout, qwerty. Besides pycharm other applications run OK. I use microsoft code as well and everything is OK with keys. This is annoying. But anyway I swiched C-W by C-Z. Now on the editor shows C-W but it does C-Z

Comment: looks like pycharm thinks my keyboard is azerty

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. Pycharm wrongly thinks my keyboard was azerty. I indeed have two layouts, french and british. pycharm wrongly didnot take the current layout into account. I dropped the french layout and now it is working correctly. Still this is a pycharm ide bug: not taking into account the current system layout.

Comment: This bug is still present in version 2023.3.4

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm defines these things as a `Keymap`. You can view what PyCharm's current keymap is, change it, search by function, or search by "shortcut".

> File -> Settings -> Keymap

From there you can change the keymap however you like.

Comment: Exactly, but what is driving me crazy is that on the keymap I found Undo assigned to Crtl+Z. And moreover when I try to change and I wrote Crtl-Z it writes into the editor Ctrl-W!, this how I learnt the keystrokes where exchanged.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around.
When I was working with my English keyboard layout it detected a Z when it should be a W.
To use the W eg to do a `CTRL + W` keymapping for jumping to the next tab with the VIM plugin do the following:

- go from EN keyboard layout to your alternative layout
- now go and type in the key mapping you initially wanted to configure
- now change your system keyboard layout back to EN
- pycharm will now apply the keymapping you wanted

Comment: for clarification my actual keyboard is standard US qwerty.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to enable `Use national layouts for shortcuts`
I initially searched for it but couldn't find it. The setting can be found at the bottom of `Settings>Keymap`
[image: enable national layouts here]